# Adding Records to MS Access database with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception, ms-access

I am writing a simple application to add records to a database that is powered by MS Access. The following is an example of my code. I'm not sure why it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim dsTable As DataTable
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsTable = New DataTable("Customers")
        dsNewRow = dsTable.NewRow()
        CustomersDataSet.Customers.Rows.Add(NameTextBox.Text, AddrTextBox.Text, ZipTextBox.Text, "", "", BalanceTextBox.Text, CreditLimitTextBox.Text, StatusTextBox.Text)


    End Sub
```

Here is a copy of the exception I am getting:

```
System.Data.ConstraintException was unhandled
  Message=Column 'Name' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'd' is already present.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.UniqueConstraint.CheckConstraint(DataRow row, DataRowAction action)
       at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
       at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
       at System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)
       at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
       at IS349_FP_Hill.addCustomer.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Monty\Documents\IS349-FP-Hill\IS349-FP-Hill\IS349-FP-Hill\addCustomer.vb:line 19
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at IS349_FP_Hill.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your data table doesn't have any defined columns, so I suspect the `Add` will fail.

Comment: Hi Mogul, please include any error messages you're getting. Thank you

Comment: the error says the value already exist in your table. That column `Name` can only take one unique value. If `John` was in the table you cannot add `John` again. The error actually said `Value "d"`

Comment: This isn't true though because when I open the DB, "John" isnt in there. @codingbiz

Comment: You have "", "" as fields to be added. MS Access is generally not set-up to permit zero-length strings in fields (columns) and a query including them would fail.

Comment: TheMogul, @codingbiz was right, you are trying to add the same value ("d") into the Name field when it already exists (and is a Unique field).

Comment: @NoAlias What I am trying to say is that message is false because there is no "d" in the name field.

Comment: Probably looking at the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what's wrong:

```
Message=Column 'Name' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'd' is already present.
```

This means 2 things:

1. The column is set to have only unique values (so you can't have 2 rows that have the same data in each of their `Name` fields)
2. The value `d` is already stored in the `Name` column somewhere and the unique constraint won't allow you to add it again.

You'll have to figure out how to remove the unique constraint on the column. I don't work with MS Access, so I can't help much there, but this should get you started:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177883%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I suggest you work on listing constraints or getting full table schema ([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013028/how-to-get-table-schema)) first...

Hope this helps!

Good Luck