# Pulling meta data off a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, metadata, html-select

Im coding in Microsoft Visual Studio in ASP.net using C#. The code below describes how I bind an ACCESS database to pull data from it in my dropdownlist.

```
private void BindDatatomydropdown()
{
    string myconnectionstr = "path";
    string mySelectQuery = "SELECT Name,Sales FROM xxxxxxtable";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(myconnectionstr))
    {
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, conn);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(myCommand);
        DataSet dss = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dss);
        DropDownList2.DataSource = dss;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Sales";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

My Question is: How can I pull the meta data of the tables in the database? so the database has 2 tables. one of which is xxxxsales. and xxxxsales has the following columns: name, id, region,  sales, year.
So what do I write my sql statement as in order to pull those columns??

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear why you want the metadata for?

Comment: Why do I need to explain the reason for its use? I am new and testing to see if there is a way to pull meta data from a table using C#

Comment: I asked because it is not common for ASP.NET application to work with metadata since this process slows the application performance. There are rare cases when an application programmer need to write code for that. This may provide some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013028/how-to-get-table-schema

Comment: The reason as to why i am doing it is because, the database that I will be using in the near future has over 30 columns in each table and I do not wish to create 30 filters for a report, much rather prefer to have two drop down list to provide visual on the filter items being selected. Sorry for being rude earlier.

Comment: No problem, I don't know your application but generally, users don't tend to use all the database columns when they query the db. Users typically have a set of queries they run to do their business. Also letting the user to do with the database as you'd do in SQL SELECT would cause performance issue for large tables. :)

Comment: You are absolutely correct with the performance issue. The task that I will be doing in the future requires me to either implement a way the allows the users to access all of the components of a table in a database regardless of the performance. The only reason to that is no one wants to touch the back end code. And IF performance will be an issue, then I would have to find an alternative then. What would u suggest if performance is required on a large dataset. How would access all the columns with balancing performance?

Comment: To start with MS-Access is not a good choice for web applications with several users. If you have 100,000 rows in your db and you let users write queries that would not use indexes, there is no way to guarantee performance. The best approach is to carefully study user needs. This is also important for you so that you can design a good and practical GUI.

Comment: Well from the looks of it, it seems like I have another task to accomplish before I finalize a design. Thanks for your help Emmad!! Much appreciated, I will be deciding how the GUI and even the back end code will work if performance becomes an issue. The database will most probably be either 100,000 rows or bigger. Thanks again :)