# Whether Database Objects exists or not

Tags: vb.net

Well I have not worked on MSAccess before, I want to check whether my table is exists in database or not

Thanks in advance

Dinesh Chauhan

Comment: See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013028/how-to-get-table-schema

Comment: How are you connecting to Access DB via vb.net? Can you post some relevant code?