# How to check if two separate DBs have the same tables/queries/etc?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two DBs in different versions. How can I see if all its tables/queries/etc are the same in both versions and which of them has any tables/queries/etc the other does not?

it is not very interesting to do it by hand because there are hundreds and hundreds of access objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the answers to this question:

[How to get table Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013028/how-to-get-table-schema)

It's suggested you query the following tables:

- MSysAccessObjects
- MSysAccessXML
- MSysACEs
- MSysObjects
- MSysQueries
- MSysRelationships

You could setup a 3rd database that as links back to the other two databases, then do joins between the tables mentioned in the above posting.

Worse case (like having issues with linking to system tables) you could just copy-paste the contents into a 3rd database, or even Excel.

Not a great every-day solution, but for those one-off needs, it should work.